# Tasks: How to nest tasks in newcommand?

Tags: tasks

I would like to perform a few tasks at the beginning of the document so that I can later use them in a defined environment.

Why doesn't the following work?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}

\section{Works not}
\newcommand\examples{%
\task Sample
\task Sample
\task Sample
}

\newcommand\Examples{%
%\settasks{debug}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
\examples
\end{tasks}}%

\Examples

\section{Works}
\newcommand\ExamplesII{%
%\settasks{debug}
\begin{tasks}[style=itemize](2)
\task Sample
\task Sample
\task Sample
\end{tasks}}%

\ExamplesII
\end{document}
```

Comment: The environment splits the body at every occurrence of the token `\task`. In order to do that it needs to explicitly see the token(s) `\task`, it cannot be hidden in another macro.

Comment: And no possible trick too?

Comment: I think so. ;) .....................